# Replace Multiple Spaces and Newlines with only one space in PHP

Tags: php, string, whitespace, normalize

I have a string with multiple newlines.

The String:

```
This is         a dummy text.               I need              




to                                      format
this.
```

Desired Output:

```
This is a dummy text. I need to format this.
```

I'm using this:

```
$replacer  = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t", "  ");
$string = str_replace($replacer, "", $string);
```

But it is not working as desired/required. Some of the words don't have spaces between them.

Actually I need to convert the string with all the words separated by single spaces.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would encourage you to use `preg_replace`:

```
# string(45) "This is a dummy text . I need to format this."
$str = preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $str );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/no6zs3oo

You may have noted in the `" . "` portion of the first example. Spaces that are immediately followed by punctuation should probably be removed entirely. A quick modification permits this:

```
$patterns = array("/\s+/", "/\s([?.!])/");
$replacer = array(" ","$1");

# string(44) "This is a dummy text. I need to format this."
$str = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacer, $str );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/ZTX0CAGD

Comment: Yep. Got It. Thanks Again! One Question @JonathanSampson. Where Can I Learn this regex in details?