# RegEx to Find a sentence in running text

Tags: php, regex

hi looking for a regex solution to find a sentence/group of words in running text. Sentence sometimes be in a single line or wrapped into two lines. Please help.

When run against this text, there's a match:

> The case has been closed and a report has been created.

When run against this text, however, it fails to match:

> The case has been
>   closed and a report
>   has been created

I tried the following:

```
$t_pattern = "case has been closed";
preg_match($t_pattern, $var['subject'], $regs)
```

Basically, I'm searching in body of an email for the sentence to close a ticket. The response is sent from a support ticket system. Although it works when the entire sentence is one line like example 1, it fails in cases similar to example 2.

Comment: @J.Steen Spaces and or newlines actually.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use regex for searching that particular string.

Just use a [regex replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to normalize linebreaks (and other whitespaces), and then use simple [substring search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$t_pattern = "case has been closed";
$subject = preg_replace('/\s+/', " ", $var['subject']);
strpos($subject, $t_pattern)
```

Comment: preg_replace('/\s+/g', " ", $var['subject']); is returning empty string

Comment: @Manju: I'm no PHP pro, it seem like it didn't like the *global* flag. See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1703320/1048572) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10810211/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay with

```
$t_pattern = "/case\s+has\s+been\s+closed/";
```

The `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters, including newlines.